# EF Core - Creating Unexpected Incomplete Rows in Sql Server LocalDb

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a new VS2022 solution with EFCore 6.0.1 available at: https://github.com/RobBowman/BillByTime

I've created a db context to represent the following:

[image: db_diagram]

I've used EFCore Power Tools from with VS2022 and compared the diagram it creates against my intended schema - they match!

Here is the db context C#:

```
public class BillByTimeContext : DbContext
    {
        public BillByTimeContext(DbContextOptions<BillByTimeContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            RelationalDatabaseCreator databaseCreator =
                        (RelationalDatabaseCreator)this.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();
            databaseCreator.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public DbSet<ClientOrg>? ClientOrg { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contract>? Contract { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PurchaseOrder>? PurchaseOrder { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tenant> Tenant { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TenantManager>? TenantManager { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Timesheet>? Timesheet { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TimesheetHistory>? TimesheetHistory { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Worker>? Worker { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>()
                .HasIndex(x => x.Name)
                .IsUnique();

            modelBuilder.Entity<TenantManager>()
                .HasIndex(x => x.Email)
                .IsUnique();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Worker>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Contracts)
                .WithOne(t => t.Worker)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Timesheet>()
                .HasMany(p => p.TimesheetHistories)
                .WithOne(t => t.Timesheet)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Worker>()
                .HasMany(p => p.TimesheetHistories)
                .WithOne(t => t.Worker)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
                .Property(x => x.UnitCharge)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseOrder>()
                .Property(x => x.Amount)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Timesheet>()
                .Property(x => x.Monday)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Timesheet>()
                .Property(x => x.Tuesday)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Timesheet>()
                .Property(x => x.Wednesday)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Timesheet>()
                .Property(x => x.Thursday)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Timesheet>()
                .Property(x => x.Friday)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Timesheet>()
                .Property(x => x.Saturday)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Timesheet>()
                .Property(x => x.Sunday)
                .HasPrecision(10, 2);
        }

    }
```

I have an xunit test that calls the following *SeedData* method:

```
public static void SeedData(BillByTimeContext context)
        {

            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var timesheetHistory = new TimesheetHistory
            {
                Timestamp = new DateTime(2022, 1, 7, 14, 30, 0),
                StatusId = TimesheetStatus.PendingApproval
            };

            var timesheet = new Timesheet
            {
                Monday = 1,
                Tuesday = .5M,
                Wednesday = 1,
                Thursday = 0,
                Friday = 1,
                WeekCommencingMonday = new DateTime(2022, 01, 03),
                TimesheetHistories = new List<TimesheetHistory> { timesheetHistory },
            };

            var purchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrder
            {
                DateIssued = DateTime.Now,
                Amount = 5462.5M,
                Timesheets = new List<Timesheet> { timesheet }
            };

            var clientManager = new ClientManager
            {
                FirstName = "Paul",
                LastName = "Arndel",
                Email = "p.arndel@brc.com",
                SmsNumber = "867428764",
                TimesheetHistories = new List<TimesheetHistory> { timesheetHistory }
            };

            var contract = new Contract
            {
                UnitId = ContractUnits.Days,
                UnitCharge = 550,
                Timesheets = new List<Timesheet> { timesheet }
            };

            var clientOrg = new ClientOrg
            {
                Name = "BRC",
                PurchaseOrders = new List<PurchaseOrder> { purchaseOrder },
                ClientManagers = new List<ClientManager> { clientManager },
                Contracts = new List<Contract> { contract },
                Timesheets = new List<Timesheet> { timesheet }
            };

            var tenantManager = new TenantManager
            {
                FirstName = "Rob",
                LastName = "Bowman",
                Email = "rob@biztalkers.com",
                ClientOrgs = new List<ClientOrg> { clientOrg }
            };

            var worker = new Worker
            {
                FirstName = "Fabio",
                LastName = "Capello",
                Email = "f.cap@ital.com",
                Contracts = new List<Contract> { contract },
                TimesheetHistories= new List<TimesheetHistory> { timesheetHistory }
            };

            var tenant = context.Tenant.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "BizTalkers");
            if (tenant == null)
            {
                context.Tenant.Add(new Tenant
                {
                    Name = "BizTalkers",
                    TenantManagers = new List<TenantManager> { tenantManager },
                    Workers = new List<Worker> { worker }
                }); ;
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
```

If I clear all data from the db and run the test, it gives the following error:

```
---- Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Tenant' with unique index 'IX_Tenant_Name'. The duplicate key value is ()
```

Can anyone please let me know why it's trying to create multiple records in the "Tenant" table?

Comment: Does the error message actually say `The duplicate key value is ()`? Looks like the Name is blank/null if so too...

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, seems it’s trying to insert a row in the Tenant table with an empty value for the Name column

Comment: Should you be seeding your data in the unit test ? Shouldnt the data be seeded in your first EF migration and then never again ? Otherwise you can only ever run this unit test once unless as you said, you clear all the data

Comment: Although it makes use of xunit, it's not a unit test and never run from the CI pipeline. It's just a handy way to check I've setup the db context to work with the db schema I'm after.

Comment: when you clear the data to restart are you dropping it all and creating it again ? or just doing a DELETE manually ?

Comment: I'm just running delete from statements in management studio

Comment: Can you show the definitions of TenantManager and Worker classes? These are the only two I can *reasonably* see would accidentally create a new Tenant (e.g. if they have a `public Tenant Tenant {get; set; } = new()` or similar in constructor) and thus EF comes to know of a graph that contains multiple Tenant entities, at least 2 of which have a blank name

Comment: Before you save, have you used the debugger to inspect the graph of waiting entities to see what it contains?

Comment: @CaiusJard all of the code is in the GitHub repo: https://github.com/RobBowman/BillByTime . You could be onto something re TenantManager class. This does contain the code you described - as a navigation property to the parent Tenant class. I've done that in the same way as illustrated from the Post to Blog class in the MS Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: I didn't see anywhere in the MS article do anything like `= new()` on a navigate-from-child-to-parent prop; is it something you added in to your code or did EFCPT generate them that way?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes you're quite right - the =new() was by bad! Thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh.. just noticed you github linked your entire project - which was useful and confirmed what I suspected:

```
//worker class
public Tenant Tenant { get; set; } = new();


//tenantmanager class
public Tenant Tenant { get; set; } = new();
```

Every time you make a new worker, it makes a new Tenant. EF will see this as an object that has to be saved. Your graph contains at least 1 worker (with 1 tenant with a blank name) and 1 tenantmanager (with 1 tenant with a blank name) so it looks like

```
{Tenant "BizTalkers"} --has-some--> [ {Worker "Fabio"} --has-one--> { Tenant "" } ]
           \
            `--has-some--> [ {TenantManager "Rob"} --has-one--> { Tenant "" } ]
```

At the moment I don't know why EFCPT has generated the entities that way (if it even did?) - mine doesn't. I'm not sure if it's an option you've toggled on, or a consequence of something in the DB end.. I'll update the answer if I find something, but for now your problem is, I believe, being caused by this. Either remove the `= new()` from these props, or set them null in your initializer, or build the graph the other way (set the Tenant you create to be the Tenant of the Worker you create, overwriting the `new() Tenant` it has, rather than setting the Worker you create to be one of the Workers of the Tenant you create)

Also, footnote, generally I would say "avoid wholesale replacing the entire list of child entities" - these collections are usually `new`'d in a constructor/class prop initializer as empty HashSets for a reason, and you'd simply Add to them rather than replacing them. If you replace them the change tracker might think you're deleting stuff and all sorts of crazy will happen

Comment: To clarify - EFCPT didn’t generate the entities, I only used it to generate a diagram. So, the fault of this issue was entirely made by me and my use of the =new(); for the navigation properties

Comment: Phew, I was thinking I'd have to call ErikEJ in here! You can get EFCPT to generate them by the way, and a nice job it makes too. It shortens the dev cycle a little to pop open SSMS, make a new database diagram, draw the tables etc like you have your ERD there, drag the relationships etc etc, and then save to create the DB and tell EFCPT to Reverse Engineer it into a bunch of classes for you. It does all the setup (similar to Scaffold-DbContext) but with a few more tweaks and such possible

Comment: Thanks Caius, I only discovered EFCPT today but it looks like it is going to be a great help